# Why is git (bitbucket) proving totally ineffective and useless for my project? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have been trying to learn git for months now, only because everyone says how wonderful and what an absolute necessity it is. This is not meaning to be a slam on GIT, I only want to know what I am missing or doing wrong, because after 2 months I'm still not seeing it.

GIT seems to be more about managing multiple people editing the same stuff, rather than about managing actual version control (assuming you only have one programmer). i.e. it appears to be based on a model where everything gets merged or pushed back to the main branch; there doesn't appear to be a way to lock a branch so nothing can be merged with it. Am I wrong? Here is what I am trying to do:

[image]

1. upload my 40k line project to bitbucket for the first time.
2. create 3 discrete 'versions' (or branches I think).
3. Ensure the 3 versions cannot be merged, **ensure I can edit the main branch to push those early bug fixes forward safely, without overwriting other version specific code, and without having to edit every file up the chain**.
4. Create the versions by slimming down or beefing up the functionality of the 3 branches from the first upload.
5. Continue developing each version all the way up to 10.5.2.3.45, never merging the versions.

My development unit is a real server. I'm a visual person, git at command line I think would be a disaster for me. I'm the only programmer. I don't want to have to upload to bit bucket to do this, but I will if it does what I need.

Cisco is a company with a horrible version management philosophy, every piece of hardware has 40 supported versions unique to that version all from the same line (i.e. they probably have 300 active branches or versions of IOS at any point, constantly branching off each as a customer calls locking for a patch to a avoid a full update). This is what I am seeking to manage, not multiple programmers. For example, here is what I would expect to see on git after a year (my situation will not be as bad as Ciscos... I just want all versions maintained and graphed nicely). 
[image]

It's almost like I'm doing everything right, but bitbucket only shows one branch at a time... I need the full map, I don't see how it would be useful to a single programmer otherwise (by single I mean 'not multiple programmers'). Here is what I can actually do with bitbucket:
[image]
[image]

Then I see this when I look at a main branch:
[image]

Do you see the issue? Basically I'm used to managing software with Visio, a solid folder structure and version system, and comparison software when a rare merge was required (99.9% of the time when I work with other programmers we are writing things in a modular fashion, so conflicts are very rare). What I'm seeing on bit bucket is so different from what I am used to, and it seems convoluted, dangerous and difficult compared to my method... though I 100% see the advantage if I had 100 programmers under me dispersed throughout the globe. What am I missing? I really don't want to use bit bucket if it can't do what I can do with Visio in 2 minutes. I have to be missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure this is appropriate for StackOverflow, but yes, git on a host like github or bitbucket really *is* for multiple-user collaboration, and git has a lot of stuff in it that's meant to help out with that, none of which is useful for your particular situation.  You *can* use git (and bitbucket) for what you want to do, but it's not really aimed at that.

Comment: Thank you, assuming no one disagrees that is exactly what I needed. I can stop wasting so many hours trying to figure it out now and get back to the actual programming. And if you know of a tool that would be good for the above, please by all means let me know... because I don't really have a way other than manually to fix a common bug in all three versions other than to do it 3 times, (copy/paste isn't such a big deal, but I thought automatically doing it would be nice git bells and whistles).

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to base my answer on a large part of the names you chose for the branches since I don't have much information about your situation.

**Those three branches you chose are actually three different projects.**

What you most likely need to do is correctly modularize/refactor your projects such that their is a fourth (or more) shared project(s).... And that project has versions and is included in the other projects as a dependency (like a library). I don't know what your codebase is but basically this involves using **dependency management** which is actually very different than **SCM/Version Control**. If your using Java its Maven/Ivy, if your using ruby its bundler, node its npm, etc... OR you can use [Git's submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) as a poorman's dependency management. Consequently if you really want the easiest but perhaps not the best I would seriously consider just using Git submodules.

**EDIT:** Given your comments on heterogenous technology I would recommend Git/Mercurial's submodules and/or [Twitters Pants Build system](http://pantsbuild.github.io/). Since its mainly web based you should also look into [bower](http://bower.io/). You will have to google dependency management for PHP but I would imagine Pants/Bower can handle it. Your absolutely right that RPM/Debian packages can be used for course grain dependency management as well as even Docker images. Sadly Dependency management has lots of (confusing) options (compared to SCM).

As far as visibility of all your projects and how they are connected I don't really have a strong recommendation. Some people use their CI UI (Jenkins, Travis) others use their SCM UI (bitbucket, github). In some cases you can even use your dependency management tools (e.g. maven dependency report) to give you an idea.

Finally given your aversion to making loosy goose branches (which is actually common in corp environments) you might want to consider Mercurial which in my opinion has some nice features for atypical workflows, eschews history editing and has permanent named branches (just an opinion for large companies not my overall opinion).

Comment: I do have a slight aversion to lose branches, more so that I really don't have a need for them... very rarely will I let a low level programmer into my main line; I have them write functions, classes or modules which I review in absolute detail, then incorporate into the main program or loop (I've written software for nuclear plants, so my approach to programming isn't loosey goosey). A more automated version control system that is fancier than I can do with named folders would be wonderful, if one exists; a way to push changes forward would be wonderful to, to deal with common code.

Comment: I think you are right, these should be considered 3 isolated projects. I just got to be very careful, I have to ensure I check the other two before fixing a bug in the one I'm looking at. It would be great to isolate the common code from the 3 versions so I wouldn't have to do that... but how would I do that... needs some thought. My program: CentOS 7 hardware appliance NAS server... my code is mostly an interface to it... code consists of javascript/php/css/html front end, mariadb middle man and python backend. Lots of little pieces to consider... also looking at RPMs in parallel.